# Why was the rice component added to 气 to form 氣?

Tags: characters, etymology, glyph-origin, character-components

[气](http://www.zdic.net/z/1c/zy/6C14.htm) is an ancient character that has roots in an oracle bone pictogram, but [according to this](http://www.zdic.net/z/1c/js/6C23.htm), the rice radical was added in the Tang dynasty to form 氣.

What were the reasons for this? What does 气, meaning gas, air or life force, have to do with rice?

Note: this question is not about traditional vs simplified.

Comment: You can see the [说文解字 tab on that page](http://www.zdic.net/z/1c/sw/6C23.htm).

Comment: Ha ha, @Stan the mighty sometimes make mistake :D Your reference treats 氣 as different meaning as modern 气. There's some merging story behind. See my answer later.

Comment: @congliu actually I was conscious of that. I didn't put it as an answer because I didn't know **when** 餼(饩) and 氣(气) were merged XD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

說文解字 has both references for [氣](http://www.zdic.net/z/1c/sw/6C23.htm) and [气](http://www.zdic.net/z/1c/sw/6C14.htm).

Put simply, 气 and 氣 comes from different origin and somehow merge together into one stream later.

In detail: 米 is not added to 气 to get 氣 in Tang Dynasty. Long time ago, 氣 appears in the form of [Bronze inscription](http://www.vividict.com/WordInfo.aspx?id=2046), though different meaning as 气. 氣 is originally designed to mean the "air generated from digesting food". While 气 is originally designed to mean the physical gas. In the reference of 氣, "饋客芻米也" means "氣 is a verb, showing the action of giving guest fodder (芻, chu2) and rice (米) as gift." 饋 (kui4) is "to give someone gift". 氣 with this meaning later becomes [餼](http://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=gb&char=%E9%A4%BC) to clarify the action relating to food.

So nowadays, in Taiwan, [氣為餼之異體](http://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/yitib/ldb/ldb05748.htm) (氣 is another non-standard variant of 餼). Also, according the [教育部異體字字典](http://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/) 气為氣之異體 (气 is another non-standard variant of 氣). In China mainland, 氣 is replaced by 气 as standard.

Comment: Ah. That's "rice" to know.

Comment: 氣 did not originally mean "air generated from digesting food." It meant "grain offering." There is a very detailed analysis here on this very question: http://www.hongyuandong.com/blog/linguistics/the-etymology-of-%E6%B0%94-qi/

Answer (score 5):

The original character for the meaning *gas, atmosphere* is 「气」, while using 「氣」 for this meaning is strictly a [phonetic loan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification#Rebus_(phonetic_loan)_characters).

「氣」 ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)): **/*qʰ(r)ə[t]-s/**) originally meant *gifting food to someone*, comprised from semantic
「米」 (*rice*) and phonetic 「气」 (**/*C.qʰəp-s/**). This word is now written as 「餼」.

---

「气」 was originally a picture of thin clouds.

<kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image: 气]
[前](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)7.36.2
[合集12532](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=12532&jgwfl=)</kbd>

The stylisation that occurred to form the modern shape of 「气」 was firstly to differentiate the character from the similar-looking 「三」.

<kbd>[春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image: 气]
洹子孟姜壺
[集成9730](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=9730&jgwfl=)</kbd>
<kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
[image: 气]
[气部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77389&page=27)
[說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd><kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image: 气]
[法](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)115
[睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)</kbd>

Later on, the character became used as a phonetic loan for a word **/*C.qʰət/**, *to beg*, *request*, and thus the meaning *gas, atmosphere* 「气」 started to be written differently from the meaning *beg, request* 「乞」.

- 「气」

  <kbd>[東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han)
  [隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
  [image: 气]
  魯峻碑</kbd>
  　
  <kbd>[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
  [image: 气]</kbd>
- 「乞」

  <kbd>東漢
  隸
  [image: 乞]
  武梁祠畫象</kbd>
  　
  <kbd>楷
  [image: 乞]</kbd>

「氣」 was first created to represent the unrelated word now written as 「餼」. Probably, due to the potential confusion caused by 「气」 and 「乞」 being the same character,「氣」 became used as a phonetic loan for the word meaning *gas, atmosphere*, and eventually became the overwhelmingly preferred way of writing this word.

To write the word originally written as 「氣」, semantic 「食」 (*food*) was later added to form 「餼」.

---

**References:**

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)
- [中國哲學書電子化計劃](https://ctext.org/)

  - [宋・徐鉉等奉敕校定　漢・許慎《說文解字》](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&res=77351)

Answer (score 2):

I remember reading somewhere that it's a pictograph of the steam  or vapor 气 coming from boiling rice 米. But here's what wiktionary says about its etymology:
Original form of 餼／饩 ("to present rice as a gift"), which is from the same source as 乞 ("to endow, to beg"). Current meaning came from phonetic loan. Cognate with 愾／忾 ("anger, hatred").

Answer (score 1):

Wiktionary says:

> - 氣: Phono-semantic compound (形聲, OC *kʰɯds, *qʰɯds): phonetic 气 (OC *kʰɯds) + semantic 米 (“rice”) – to give rice as a gift.
> - 气 (OC *kʰɯds) is a pictogram (象形) of clouds flowing through the sky. In the oracle bone script, it was represented by three horizontal strokes, expressing the "feeling" of the sky. However, in order to avoid confusion with the number 三 (OC *suːm, *suːms), the current 气 (OC *kʰɯds) was changed to draw a small stroke from top to bottom. The glyph of 氣 (OC *kʰɯds, *qʰɯds) and 乞 (OC *kʰɯds, *kʰɯd) comes from the same ancient form.
> - 乞: Variant of 气 (OC *kʰɯds), distinguished to indicate a phonetically borrowed meaning “to beg”.

For some reason, later 氣 came to take 气's meaning of air, possibly to distinguish it from 乞.

In the creation of Simplified Chinese, 氣 was changed back to 气.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion,the rice is a kind of food. If someone don't eat anything,he will dead,and no longer  breath. So, if no food,then no breath.
My english is not good. Hope to help you .

Comment: Welcome to Chinese SE. This question is seeking evidence/facts for why the radical was added, and not an opinion. Please provide some sort of research to back up your claim. Thank you.